# Strange behavior with doctrine_record::free() method on a loop

Tags: php, doctrine

Hie all,

I loop in Doctrine_Query::execute() with many relations and i get a 
record on each iteration. No problem.

To save memory, i would like free() record memory usage with 
Doctrine_Record::free().

The first iteration, no problem but at the next one my new object 
loose relation. 
Example :

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create() 
  ->From(..) 
  ->leftJoin(...) 
  ->innerJoin(Relationship) 
  ->where(...) 
  ->andWhere(...); 
foreach($q->execute() as $r) 
{ 
   $val = $r->Relationship->get(colx); 
   $r->free(true); 
}
```

At the second iteration, i get new record but without innerJoin Relationship ???

Any idea...

Thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

As it states in the method comments and the [API reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/1.2/doctrine/doctrine_record.html)

> Helps freeing the memory occupied by the entity. Cuts all references the entity has to other entities and removes the entity from the instance pool. Note: The entity is no longer useable after free() has been called. **Any operations done with the entity afterwards can lead to unpredictable results.**

You shouldn't use `free()`, especially if you intend to use the record afterwards. The only case you should need to use it is if you're loading an extremely large number of records and you need to free up memory.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do necessary things before free() record and when i get the next one, relationship missing for the next record.. There's one thing i don't get in head!!??

Comment: @geoffroy My guess is that somewhere, you have a circular reference to the parent. Passing `true` to the `free()` method will free every related object too. Try using `$r->free();` instead. For more info, [read the documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/nl/improving-performance:free-objects)

Comment: but $r is not the same object at each iteration. I destroy circular reference on the current $r in the loop but not for the next $r in the next iteration.. Thanks for your help

Comment: @geoffroy I can see a fairly simple solution here. Just don't use it. If you insist on using it, you're on your own. I can't tell without seeing your relationship structure.